# Die statement is not working in foreach loop in perl

Tags: perl

My script downloads files from FTP and moves the files to the archive directory in the FTP.
I have a pattern to search for files in FTP, and have put it in foreach loop to get those files to local directory.

```
my $ftpUser     = 'xxxx';
my $ftpPW       = 'xxxxxx';
my $FTPHost     = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
my $remotefile  = 'CAP*.csv';
my $archivefile = "/usr/archive/CAP_${file_date_time}.csv";

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($FTPHost);
$ftp->login( $ftpUser, $ftpPW ) or die print L1 "Could not login FTP :" . $ftp->message . "\n";
print L1 "Login to FTP was successfull\n";
$ftp->cwd("/")
    or die print L1 "ftp_cd failed: " . $ftp->message . "\n";
foreach my $file_to_fetch ( $ftp->ls($remotefile) ) {
    $ftp->get( $file_to_fetch, $localfile ) or die print L1 "Could not get file from FTP :" . $ftp->message . "\n";
    $remotefile = $file_to_fetch;
    print "\$file_to_fetch ::: $file_to_fetch\n";
    print L1 "File - ${file_to_fetch} Successfully Downloaded from FTP\n";
    $ftp->rename( $file_to_fetch, $archivefile )
        or die print L1 "Could not move file to archive directory :" . $ftp->message . "\n";
    print L1 "File - ${file_to_fetch} Moved to archive directory as CAP_${file_date_time}.csv\n";
}
$ftp->quit;

print L1 "FTP process was successfully completed\n";
if ( -s $localfile ) {
    open F1, "$localfile"
        or die( print L1 "$localfile cannot be opened for reading \n" );
} else {
    die( print L1 "$localfile does not exist \n" );
}
```

While executing the above code, if the file i am searching was not there in FTP but it is not printing the die statement which is "Could not get file from FTP " log, instead it comes out of FTP and proceeds with the next set of code which is print L1 "FTP process was successfully completed\n".

Please help me on these, why the die statement is not working in the foreach, if it was not able to get files from FTP.

Answer (score 2):

Replace,

```
$ftp->get($file_to_fetch,$localfile) or die print L1 "Could not get file from FTP :" . $ftp->message ."\n";
```

with

```
$ftp->get($file_to_fetch,$localfile) or die "Could not get file from FTP :". $ftp->message ."\n";
```

as `die` in first case takes `print()` return value as argument instead of error message.

Alternatively make your own function,

```
sub mydie {
  my ($msg) = @_;

  print L1 $msg;
  die $msg;
}
```

or if function is not an option,

```
$ftp->get($file_to_fetch,$localfile) or do {

  print(L1 $_), die($_) for "Could not get file from FTP :". $ftp->message ."\n";
};
```

Comment: Please leave comment when down voting correct answer.

Comment: This answer doesn't address why the code doesn't die, which is the question.

Comment: @darch OP wants to print and die with same message, and program prints what he wants but dies with `1` message. Answer above explains why there is no desired behavior, and how to accomplish it. So code definitively dies (https://eval.in/205481) but not in a way that OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arrises because you're passing the return value from a `print` statement to `die`:

```
... or die print L1 "Could not get file from FTP :" . $ftp->message . "\n";
```

I suspect that you're trying to mirror the output from your die statement both to a file and to STDERR.

If that's the case, then I recommend that you do the following:

1. Change all `die print L1` statements to just `die`
2. Remove the trailing newline `\n` from each of your `die` messages as that hides the line number information.

   ```
   $ftp->login( $ftpUser, $ftpPW )
       or die "Could not login FTP :" . $ftp->message;
   ```
3. Create a `$SIG{__DIE__}` handler to mirror your `die` output to the file handle.

   ```
   local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
       print L1 @_;
       die @_;
   };
   ```

Comment: Yeah, half an hour ago.  I consider the information of assistance to the OP and potentially others regardless, so was just going to ignore it.